# Trouble calling a non-static method from an abstract class

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to call `getSetting()` from SettingsItem.java in SingleChoiceViewHolder.java. Is there a way to call `getSetting()` while keeping `SettingsItem` a non-static abstract class? Here's what I tried to add to SingleChoiceViewHolder.java, however Android Studio says that 'SettingsItem' is abstract; cannot be instantiated.:

```js
SettingsItem instance = new SettingsItem();
instance.getSetting();

IntSetting setting = (IntSetting) getSetting();
mTextSettingDescription.setText(setting.getValue());
```

I also tried I tried converting SettingsItem to an interface and implementing it alongside `SingleChoiceViewHolder extends SettingViewHolder` but the original problem still remained.

The files are attached below.

SingleChoiceViewHolder.java:

```js
public final class SingleChoiceViewHolder extends SettingViewHolder
{
 private SingleChoiceSetting mItem;

 private TextView mTextSettingName;
 private TextView mTextSettingDescription;

 public SingleChoiceViewHolder(View itemView, SettingsAdapter adapter)
 {
  super(itemView, adapter);
 }

 @Override
 protected void findViews(View root)
 {
  mTextSettingName = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.text_setting_name);
  mTextSettingDescription = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.text_setting_description);
 }

 @Override
 public void bind(SettingsItem item)
 {
  mItem = (SingleChoiceSetting) item;

  mTextSettingName.setText(item.getNameId());

  if (item.getDescriptionId() == R.string.dynamic_descriptionId)
  {
   SettingsItem instance = new SettingsItem();
   instance.getSetting();

   IntSetting setting = (IntSetting) getSetting();
   mTextSettingDescription.setText(setting.getValue());
  }

  if (item.getDescriptionId() > 0 && item.getDescriptionId() != R.string.dynamic_descriptionId)
  {
   mTextSettingDescription.setText(item.getDescriptionId());
  }
 }

 @Override
 public void onClick(View clicked)
 {
  getAdapter().onSingleChoiceClick(mItem);
 }
```

SettingsItem.java:

```js
public abstract class SettingsItem
{
 public static final int TYPE_HEADER = 0;
 public static final int TYPE_CHECKBOX = 1;
 public static final int TYPE_SINGLE_CHOICE = 2;
 public static final int TYPE_SLIDER = 3;
 public static final int TYPE_SUBMENU = 4;
 public static final int TYPE_INPUT_BINDING = 5;
 public static final int TYPE_RADIO_BUTTON = 6;

 private String mKey;
 private String mSection;
 private int mFile;

 private Setting mSetting;

 private int mNameId;
 private int mDescriptionId;

 public SettingsItem(String key, String section, int file, Setting setting, int nameId, int descriptionId)
 {
  mKey = key;
  mSection = section;
  mFile = file;
  mSetting = setting;
  mNameId = nameId;
  mDescriptionId = descriptionId;
 }

 public String getKey()
 {
  return mKey;
 }

 public String getSection()
 {
  return mSection;
 }

 public int getFile()
 {
  return mFile;
 }

 public Setting getSetting()
 {
  return mSetting;
 }

 public void setSetting(Setting setting)
 {
  mSetting = setting;
 }

 public int getNameId()
 {
  return mNameId;
 }

 public int getDescriptionId()
 {
  return mDescriptionId;
 }

 public abstract int getType();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since getSetting() is not a static method, you need to invoke it on an instance of some concrete class that extends the abstract class SettingsItem.

Think about it. If you have two instances of such a class, and the mSetting variable is different for the two instances, which one should be returned from a static-like call to getSetting()?

Answer (score 0):

By definition abstract class means it is not instantiated but you can inherit from it. If you want to create many different objects with the same values but different names you can just extend SettingsItem.

Also, if you want more abstraction for future use you can create an interface with the same methods as the abstract methods in case you need to make customize methods for a different settings item.

Example:

```
interface SettingsInterface {
    void doSomething();
}

class abstract SettingsItem implements SettingsInterface {
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}

class RegularSettings extends SettingsItem {}

class CustomSettings implements SettingsInterface {
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("Goodbye");
    }
}

class TestClass {

    public static void testAbstract(SettingsItem extendedAbstract) {
        extendedAbstract.doSomething();
    }

    public static void testInterface(SettingsInterface interface) {
        interface.doSomething();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SettingsItem abstractExtended = new RegularSettings();
        // also could be CustomSettings instead of SettingsInterface
        SettingsInterface customClass = new CustomSettings();

        testInterface(abstractExtended);
        testInterface(customClass);

        testAbstract(abstractExtended);
        // will throw errors since it doesn't extend SettingsItem
        testAbstract(customClass);
    }
}
```

Comment: But then I'd need to extend both SettingViewHolder and SettingsItem. I tried converting SettingsItem to an interface and implementing it alongside `SingleChoiceViewHolder extends SettingViewHolder` but the original problem still remained.